# Десериализовать ini в класс

Tags: c#, ini

Есть проект, который содержит в себе довольно много различных `ini` файлов. Я могу с ними работать либо через доступные в WinAPI методы, либо с помощью какой либо библиотеки, но все они подразумевают использование значений из `ini` как `ini.Read("Cat", "Value");`, что не очень удобно, ибо всегда надо знать точное название переменной и ты от нее в итоге сильно зависишь.

Скажите, есть ли возможность работать с `ini` файлом, как с `JSON`? То есть создать структуру классов, десериализовать файл в нее и уже в проекте писать `ini.Cat.Value`? Может можно сделать какую либо обертку для этого или есть уже готовые решения?

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что такое решение есть, ибо `ini` устарели раньше, чем подобное вошло в моду) Но Вы ведь программист: напишите своё решение)

Comment: Сам не проверял но должно работать. Что если ini поместить в dictionary а из него сформировать JSON строку. А там если нужно можно и в класс запихнуть?!

Comment: @АртурФранк Ну это прям какой то костыль костылей) Перегонять сначала из одного формата в другой, что бы из другого формата перегнать в классы. Не уж то легче способа нет? К тому же мы потеряем первоначальный вид файла (комментарии например).

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Вот в этом вся и беда, что я не знаю как подобное вообще реализуется.

Comment: Напишите парсер (или используйте существующий), прогоните через него нужный `ini`, получите его структуру, сформируете класс из этой структуры, впилите его в свой код ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Но можно и по совету @АртурФранк: загоните в `JSON` и используйте существующие генераторы структур для данного формата. Это сэкономит Вам время)

Comment: В любом случае чтобы использовать в проекте такое выражение ini.Cat.Value вам нужно знать все имена переменных которые находятся в ini файле чтобы на его базе построить class. Или вы вздумали динамически создавать класс для парсинга ini?

Comment: @АртурФранк Да класс то я создам без проблем, здесь уже вопрос удобства в дальнейшей разработке. Ибо для меня четкая структура классов в разы удобней, чем я каждый раз по памяти (или буду смотреть в файл) буду писать название переменных. А так, раз написал в какой то класс все это и радуюсь жизни, следуя подсказкам той же студии.

Comment: То приложение тоже будет работать с этими файлами? или вам нужны данные которые находятся в этом приложении?

Comment: Тоже. Из за этого я не могу менять его формат или что то еще. Данные .ini файлы - это различные настройки для того приложения, которые он читает при запуске. Моя задача сделать удобный графический интерфейс для изменения всех этих настроек.

Comment: Я бы сформировал бы класс содержащий все настройки с подгрузкой по старинке всех значений. Из класса сделал бы `GlobalBinding : INotifyPropertyChanged` и построил бы удобный интерфейс на VMMV.

Comment: Стандартных средств нет, но судя по поиску на гитхабе - есть куча кастомных сериализаторов или оберток: https://github.com/arcnmx/serde-ini, https://github.com/MarioZ/MadMilkman.Ini

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря наводке @PashaPash я начал пробовать различные библиотеки с GitHub. Предложенные им имели ряд неудобств (например неверная кодировка, или вовсе дублирование значений).

В итоге остановился на данном проекте: [Fluffy.INI](https://github.com/angelinn/Fluffy.INI), который подошел для меня по всем критериям

Пример использования:

- Создаем как и в JSON структуру классов:

  ```
  public class PatchSection
  {
      public int UseOSAllocators { get; set; }
  }

  public class TestSection
  {
      [FluffyComment("Клевый комментарий!")]
      public string TestValue { get; set; }
  }

  public class RootIni
  {
      public PatchSection Patch { get; set; }
      public TestSection Test { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Дальше как и обычно десериализируем:

  ```
  var ini = FluffyConverter.DeserializeObject<RootIni>(File.ReadAllText("Test.ini"));
  ```
- Меняем нужное значение:

  ```
  ini.Test.TestValue = "Некое значение";
  ```
- Сериализуем и сохраняем результат:

  ```
  File.WriteAllText(iniFile, FluffyConverter.SerializeObject(ini));
  ```

Результатом будет ini файл со всем нам необходимым:

```
[Patch]
UseOSAllocators=1

[Test]
# Клевый комментарий!
TestValue=Некое значение
```